# Key binding to open a new tab and open FuzzyFinder

Tags: vim

I have installed FuzzyFinder. AS you maybe now to open FuzzyFinder file searcher, I have to write `:FufFile`.

Now I want to create a key binding that opens a new tab and open the FuzzyFinde file searcher. This is what I try:

```
map tn :tabnew :FufFile pattern:<enter>
```

but it doesn't work, it just says `"E172: Only one file name allowed"`.

Any idea?

Javier

Comment: Are you just trying to open it in a new tabpage? FuzzyFinder already has a keybinding for that [`<C-l> (|g:fuf_keyOpenTabpage|) - opens in a new tab page.`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984)

Comment: @Michael I'm pressing Ctrl+l (ell) but it doesn't do anything..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a keymapping which run two commands:

```
:map tn :tabnew \| FufFile pattern:<CR>
```